# PMD Xpath, how to compare 2 @Image?

Tags: xpath, pmd

It's is pretty easy to compare one path's @Image to a static string but how to compare 2 paths'@Image ?

**Code that should trigger the rule :**

```
public class Foo implements {
      public String checkDBConnexion() {
        try {
            int result = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("SELECT 1 FROM dual ", Integer.class);

        } catch (DataAccessException e) {
            // This is Ok : throw new MyException(test, e);
            // this is not : hrow new MyException(test);
            // This is also not ok if there are no thrown;
            return "KO : " + e.getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

Xpath for the param name of the Catch block :

```
//CatchStatement[//FormalParameter//VariableDeclaratorId]
```

Xpath for the variable name of the thrown method :

```
//ThrowStatement//Arguments//Expression//Name
```

It's easy to compare both to 'e' :

```
//CatchStatement[//FormalParameter//VariableDeclaratorId[@Image = 'e']]

//CatchStatement[//ThrowStatement//Arguments//Expression//Name[@Image = 'e']]
```

How do I compare them with eachother ?

Also if you have a link with detailled PMD XPath synthax exemple.
The basic PMD page has ... well the basic ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering myself :

```
//CatchStatement[//FormalParameter//VariableDeclaratorId/@Image = 
//ThrowStatement//Arguments//Expression//Name/@Image]
```